# Returning if condintion in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, for-loop

```
function guid (l) {
    if(l === undefined){
        l = 32;
    }
    var ascii = '';
    for(var x=0; x<l; x++){
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*(122 - 48))+48;
        var convert = String.fromCharCode(rnd);
        if(!(convert.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g))){
        // how to return 'rnd' until the lenght of the parameter is complete 
        }else{
            ascii += convert;
        }
    }
    return ascii;

}
console.log(guid());
```

This is my code. Can u give me advice how to execute my if statement ? My output now is based on how many times rnd passes the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use while for that

```
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*(122 - 48))+48;
var convert = String.fromCharCode(rnd);

while(!(convert.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g))) {
   rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*(122 - 48))+48;
   convert = String.fromCharCode(rnd);
}
```

Comment: Thak you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop and check for the length of `ascii`.

```js
function guid (l) {
    var ascii = '', convert;
    l = l || 32;
    while (ascii.length < l) {
        convert = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 48)) + 48);
        if (convert.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g)){
            ascii += convert;
        }
    }
    return ascii;

}
console.log(guid());
```